# Store a date in MySQL database using zend library

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, date

I am passing a date from a web page in the format 10/10/1970 to a MYSQL database using the ZEND library:

```
$zendDate = new Zend_Date($theValue, "dd/mm/yyyy");
$theValue = "'" . $zendDate->toString("yyyy-mm-dd") . "'";
```

but it is not working. The date is stored as 0000-00-00.

What is wrong with my code? Thank you for your help.

Donato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html

The constant mm is for minutes, not months. Use MM for months.